# How to enable Intelligent code completion in EmbedXCode

Tags: macos, arduino, xcode5

I have successfully installed `[EmbedXcode][1]` on my mac.

Steps:

Downloaded EmbedXcode
Extracted and installed
Dragged to the Applications folder.

Note: Xcode 5 was installed on my mac even before i downloaded and installed ExbedXcode.
Note: Arduino was already installed before i downloaded and installed ExbedXcode.

Then i created a new project.

```
New ---> Project ---> OS X ---> embed xcode ---> embedXcode Sketch
```

Then i gave the name and selected the `platform` which was `Lenardo`.

Now, i `build` my project, and there was no errors found.

But, still i don't see the code change colour or Intelligent code completion being activated. How can i make this to work.

A Screen shot of my project as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the code the 'Type' in the property window on the right hand side to 'C++ source'

Then for even more code sense, get the file to successfully #include "Arduino.h"

Im struggling on that step, but have the first bit sorted………..

Sorted that, I've found that dragging arduino.h to root project directory helped. (Is there a limit to directory depth searched for autocomplete??)

Answer (score 0):

Release 131 improves reference indexing for code-sense.

You need to launch a first compilation in order to have the main sketch declared as C++ code.

For more details, please refer to chapter 2 **Create a New Project** section 2 **Prepare the Project** of the User Manual ([e-book](https://itunes.apple.com/book/embedxcode/id667501748), [PDF](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lgwbhk9eubsg1sk/embedXcode%20User%20Manual.pdf?dl=1)).

[Download embedXcode](http://embedxcode.weebly.com/download.html)

*I suggest using the [contact form](http://embedxcode.weebly.com/contact.html) or the [OneDesk portal](http://embedxcode.weebly.com/onedesk.html).*